# Cannot Connect to POP Email Server via Third-Party Mail Client

Tags: domain-name-system, email, thunderbird, pop3

I am trying to set up a POP email account via a third-party mail client in my office and can't do it. I have tried both Apple's Mail app and Mozilla Thunderbird, but I keep getting told that I have incorrect login information, despite the fact that I am sure it is correct. That's because I have used the same login info to successfully connect to the email account via GMail AND to use the account on my network at home.

So I believe that there must be an issue with the local network in my office not being set up properly, but I'm not sure what I can do. I think it's a DNS issue, but again, not very familiar with how to fix DNS problems.

Let me know if you need more information and I'd be happy to provide it. Again, the exact same mail settings work for GMail and my home network, but don't work at the office. Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you telnet directly to the POP server.  See, e.g. http://smanage.tripod.com/tel.html for how to telnet in, how to use basic pop commands...

Comment: When I try to connect via telnet, I get "-ERR Authentication failed." when I enter my password.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't actually supply enough relevant data for me to compose a decent reply, but i'll try nonetheless.

First, why do you use POP? Are you sure you want to transfer all of the emails into that single computer? No, the option "leave mail on server" is not as reliable as you'd think. I do recommend using IMAP instead.

If you are certain that the server settings and login credentials are correct (they work fine in another network) you could first do a DNS comparison. Dig up your email servers name (ie mailserver.someprovider.com) and do a dns query from the command line:

```
nslookup mailserver.someprovider.com
```

Output should point to the same or similar ip address, not a company internal address.

Then again, if your companys policy is to prevent usage of 3rd party email altogether, you'd need to set up a corkscrew proxy to punch through their firewall or just use webmail.

Comment: Thanks for the response and sorry it's taken awhile to get back on this. After doing some more research, I definitely agree that IMAP is better, but my system administrator set the account up as POP. Will try to change it, but first things first I want it to work. I contacted our ISP (Time Warner Cable Business Class) and they seem to think that it is an issue with Mail Relaying. I'm somewhat skeptical since we are sending the mail through our own servers and just using them for internet, but I'm also not every familiar with the practice. Any thoughts?